# Error "if" "else" for validation of form

Tags: jquery

I need to validate a form with `if` and `else` when you click the submit button.
However something is not working, `if` everyone has to turn red if there is no value for the input. `else` removes the error class.

I tried this way:
JQuery:

```
var inp = $('.text-input');

    $("#send-lunch").click(function(err) {
        if(!$.trim(this.value) === true){
              $(".inputs-text").addClass('error');

            }else{
              $(".inputs-text").removeClass('error');
        }
    });

    inp.blur(err);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ssts2/3/)

Comment: what if you change your html class <input type="text" class="text-input" id="jogo4"> to <input type="text" class="inputs-text" id="jogo4">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this **[JsFiddle...](http://jsfiddle.net/ssts2/7/)**

I have change JQuery code as like below... So please try it...

```
var inp = $('.text-input');
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#send-lunch").click(function(err) {
    $('.text-input').each(function(){
    if($(this).val() == ''){
        alert('sp');
          $(this).addClass('error');

        }else{
          $(this).removeClass('error');
    }
    });
});
});

inp.blur(err);
```

**HTML code changes... Button close tag missing...**

```
<button id="send-lunch">submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to compare `value` with `string` instead of `boolean` as you are using `$.trim`

```
 if(!$.trim(this.value) === "true"){
```

If you do not expect the value of text is "true" then you should compare it with empty string

```
 if(!$.trim(this.value) === ""){
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your fiddle, please see the changes

```
    var inp = $('.text-input');

$("#send-lunch").click(function(err) {
    if(inp.val().length<=0){
          $(".text-input").addClass('error');

        }else{
          $(".text-input").removeClass('error');
    }
});

inp.blur(err);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sahilthadhani/ssts2/4/

Comment: but since you are using classes and that too all are same so if user keys in value in one input box, they will reflect across. You should id's in your case.

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense, but it was only valid for the first input, type in an input when all other remove the class.